# Return file parse status django ajax

Tags: json, ajax, django

I have a script which is parsing and doing some actions on a `json dir`.
I want to show file status with current number of file being parsing.
here is what i do.

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.response = _.default_response()
    unlabeled = _.path_to_dict(settings.UNLABELEDJSONS)
    for dirs in unlabeled['children']:
        for jsonFile in dirs['children']:
            if jsonFile['type']=='file':
                #file current path with generated path.
                filepath = "%s/%s/%s" % (settings.UNLABELEDJSONS,dirs['name'], jsonFile['name'])
                targetpath = "%s/%s" % (settings.DATAFILESGENERATED, jsonFile['name'])
                #Let's generate file.
                _.call_testing_script(settings.GENERATEDRDA, filepath, targetpath)
                #File generated let's move file.
                shutil.move(targetpath, settings.DATAFILES)
                #file is moved now and new path is existpath.
                existpath = "%s/%s" % (settings.DATAFILES, jsonFile['name'])
                #let's know database what we generated.
                _.processDataFile(existpath,jsonFile['name'])
    #We are done
    self.response['status'] = True
    return _.serialize_response(self.response)
```

- Now i want to show current number of file being parsing IN THE UI
- total number of files IN THE UI
- and other information IN THE UI

Q: what library or method should I use?